# Bug in jQuery UI datepicker: getDate returns incorrect date

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have a pretty simple code involving the jQuery UI datepicker:

```
$('.date-picker').datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'MM yy',
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      showButtonPanel: true,
 })
 .change(function() {
      var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
      $('#dateShow').val(date);
 });
```

The problem is that in the `change` handler I always get the today date, not the one I've picked in the calendar, every time I select another month or year. Here is [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/AlexandrAbakumov/qk5qj33u/14/).

Does anybody have an idea of what I'm doing wrong? How could such a basic use case lead datepicker's `getDate` to return an incorrect value?

**UPDATE**: The code sample is simplified and question is reformulated accordingly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There seems to be an existing bugs for this issue 
[Bug 8009](https://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8009), 
[Bug 8159](https://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8159)

It doesn't seems like its fixed in the new version. The best way to get around this issue is to use `$(this).val()` instead of `$(this).datepicker('getDate')`.

Here's a working example : http://jsfiddle.net/qk5qj33u/9/

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, those issues are all about when you set an invalid date or even null via the `setDate`. As opposed, it's always correct in my case. Or I'm missing something?

Comment: For Bug 8159, yes but Bug 8009 is the same issue as yours.

Comment: 8009: `Datepicker: getDate returns the incorrect date **when typing invalid value**`. My: `$(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1)).change();`. Could you please point to the match with my case?

Comment: It has nothing to do with SetDate. It works fine. It's about when you try to extract the date via "getDate". This is the text from that bug : I'm using the ​datepicker demo. When I input "09012013" into the input field (and then click on some whitespace to close the calendar window), it sets the date to today, according to getDate. Shouldn't getDate return Sep 12 2013?

Comment: I've updated the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AlexandrAbakumov/qk5qj33u/10/). In this version, I don't use the `setDate` and `onClose` at all. When I'm selecting a new date by clicking on a day in the calendar, `getDate` returns the date I've just selected since the second try on, though, At the first time it returns today regardless of the selection.

Comment: Ok, I see it. Thank you! Even in this version, every time you change month/year and then select a day in the calendar, `getDate` will return today. It works only if you don't change month/year.

Comment: Correct. In my opinion, just rely on $(this).val() , it seems to be working pretty consistent.

Comment: Thank you! I'll give it a try, but it'll require changes throughout the existing code and that's why that was the last resort for me. By the way, isn't there any other option to be notified of changing datepicker's value other than `change` event?

Comment: I can feel your pain bro .. Good luck !